# Keyboard backlight wont work

Tags: keyboard

on windows to turn on the keyboard back light the button was assigned to scroll lock but on Ubuntu that does not work, it's some weird keyboard i got off amazon for cheap, I think the name is Kuivn,

anyone know a fix I just started with Ubuntu today so explain it to me like i'm 5

Comment: If it needs drivers/software in Windows to do that and if there's no equivalent for Linux then it won't work. Most that I've seen are OS independent though.

Comment: What happens if you hit function+z?

Comment: nothing, with windows it was just plug in and push scroll lock and it came on, I guess that info was downloaded when I plugged in the keyboard

Comment: Typically it's FN+Scroll, not just scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Most backlight issues can be solved by running the following command in your terminal:

```
xset led on
```

This should turn the backlight on. To automatically turn the backlight on when you boot up, search for Startup Applications. Add a new entry. Give it an appropriate name and comment, and add the above command to the `Command` field. Should you need to turn your backlight off, use the same command with `off` instead of `on`.

This is the solution I use. However, there is a bug where using the xset command turns on an accessibility feature called Mouse Keys, which turns your numpad into a virtual mouse. To work around this bug, edit the `Command` field, so that it contains the following:

```
sh -c "xset led on; sleep 1; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable true; sleep 1; gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard mousekeys-enable false"
```

This will first enable the backlight, wait one second, enable Mouse Keys, wait another second, then disable Mouse Keys. I've found that a delay needs to be added, otherwise this does not work 100% of the time. As for enabling Mouse Keys before disabling, I've also found that just disabling will not work. At least, this was the case with my system.